# Lost connection to "iPhone 6” when running app

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am running my app first time in xcode 6.0.1 given below error occur.

> Restore the connection to "iPhone 6" and run "AppName" again, or if "AppName" is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > AppName.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is know issue of Xcode 6.1.

This is happened if you have 2 projects in XCode. Try doing following steps

1. Launch main process from the device.
2. Go to Project dependance Go to Debug - select attach to process-- process launched one.

Hope it will help you..

Comment: How I can Launch main process from device ??

Answer (score 5):

Just had the same issue. I fixed it by trying a combination of:

- mac restarted
- project cleaned
- iPhone restarted

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this problem,

1. Run the app in iPhone6 Simulator.
2. After that Select Debug -> Attach to process -> iPhone Simulator.

It worked for me.